# const char * vs const char ** on argv

Tags: c++

I want to get a filename from a commandline argument so I can pass it to a file-opening function, however, argv[] seems to be of type const char ** by default, even if it was defined as "const char * argv[]" in the main's arguments. My function requires const char *, is there a way to convert this two, or something?

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    memory Memory;
    Memory.loadROM(argv); // Error 'argument of type "const char **" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"'
}
```

Comment: Note that `const char *var[]` or `const char **var` is rarely what you really mean. If you don't want to change the array elements, use `const char *const var[]` or `const char *const *var` instead.

Comment: @aschepler Nope. `const char * const * const var` is right. Without the last `const`, you can do `var = some_other_thing`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When used in function parameters without being a reference type, `const char *argv[]` and `const char **argv` is **exactly identical** because the former will be adjusted to the latter.

Per N4296, Section 8.3.5p5:

> any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is
>   adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively

So `const char *argv[]` is "an array of type `const char *`" and is thus adjusted to "a pointer to `const char *`".

And since `argv` is of type `const char **`, you want to dereference it to get a `const char *`:

```
Memory.loadROM(argv[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

`argv` contains an **array** of `char *`, so if you only want one, simplify specify which you want:

```
Memory.loadROM(argv[1]);
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean) for more on what'll be in `argv`.

Answer (score -2):

The difference between `char* argv[]` and `char** argv` is actually pretty subtle, so you'll often see them used interchangeably. The typical default is `char** argv` since that's more conventional, yet the alternative isn't wrong.

In both cases `argv[0]` is the first argument. Remember that pointers act like arrays and `char* argv[]` is an array of `char*`.

Comment: Subtle? I doubt they have any difference (when used as a function parameter).

Comment: One example of a subtle difference is in the case of `char** argv` you can do `argv++` and `argv = x`, but this is not allowed in the case of `char* argv[]`. These are not things you'd normally do, especially with `argv`, but it's one of those things that's *technically* true and C and C++ are all about technicalities.

Comment: @tadman: That is false. What you say is true if `argv` was actually an array. But a parameter named `char *argv[]` is exactly `char** argv`. It is in fact a pointer, not an array. Despite the misleading syntax.

Comment: @tadman While your claim looks really intuitive, it's actually *not* defined that way. See my answer above.